# HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found when trying to run a php site on local host using microsoft webmatrix

Tags: php, webmatrix, iis-8

"The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map."

I have a different site I am working on that loads fine, I thought that IIS automatically adds handlers when you first install php on microsoft webmatrix?

Comment: I don't know much about WebMatrix, but *[back in 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/07/12/creating-php-websites-with-webmatrix.aspx)* you needed to do some manual configuration for it to work.

Comment: thanks for your help, i fixed it. i didn't know that every time i create a new site i have to re-enable php in settings. waste of an afternoon :)

Comment: Not sure, but I think you can set settings like those both on a site-level and on server-level. If you do the latter, then it automatically applies to new sites as well.